# Tomcat Workers - Connecting Tomcat and Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, configuration, mod-proxy

I'm trying to resolve an issue about connecting Apache and Tomcat with mod_proxy_ajp. From reading I found that the problem might be the numbers of workers in the Apache and the Tomcat. So I try to find the worker's definition in the Tomcat but I couldnt find any. Can it be? Can Tomcat work without a workers.properties file? I checked the imports in the Tomcat conf just to make sure that there isnt a different file name but none. How can I find out the worker's configuration of my Tomcat setup? Is there a default?

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that in some cases the Tomcat stops responding to the Apache - in the Apache log I see many errors like:
1. "(70007)The timeout specified has expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header" 
2. "ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed"
3. "(120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from 127.0.0.1:9005 (localhost)")

So I'm trying to find out maybe the Apache has more workers than the Tomcat.

I'm using Apache 2.2.15 and Tomcat 7, connected with mod_proxy ajp on a Redhat machine.

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Baba

Comment: How did you solve it..  it is happening for me too..

Comment: I did not :(
tried to define specific connector, to play with the executors...and yet it still happens.
do you have any ideas?

Comment: I tried so hard.. finally I configured tomcat as my webserver and made tomcat listen to 80 and 443 and now the application works fast and good...  If you find get a breakthrough please post it..

Comment: did you take a look at the thread dumps from when the tomcat stopped responding? in mine it looks like most of the threads are waiting for a lock that is related to log4j. i'm still investigating it...

Answer (score 0):

On Tomcat side you have to configure AJP connector in server.xml, for example:

```xml
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="9009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Comment: its configured already. the thing is that usually it work but from time to time Tomcat stops responding to the Apache. Restarting Tomcat makes it work again while restarting Apache doesnt change a thing. 

Where should I configure the worlers for the Tomcat (i dont have a workers.properties file or something like that so i dont know how it works)?